# Determining whether URL is a second-level subdirectory using PHP

Tags: php, url, subdirectory

I need a certain image to display on my website in second-level subdirectories only. So if my URL is `www.mywebsite.com/` or `www.mywebsite.com/subdirectory1/` then I don't want the image to appear.

However if my URL is `www.mywebsite.com/subdirectory1/subdirectory2/` then I do want the image to appear.

How would I go about determining if I'm in a second-level subdirectory using PHP? Would I use `is_dir`?

Answer (score 1):

```
if (count(explode("/",$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]))>=3) {
    echo "IM IN 2nd LEVEL";
} else {
    echo "IM ONLY A 1st LEVEL";
}
```

Should do it its abit of a hack but works.

Answer (score 1):

you could do:

```
$path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);

if($path){
  $elements = explode('/', trim($path, '/'));

  if(count($elements) > 1){
    // show the image...
  }

}
```

(PS: the URL needs to start with a scheme, like `http://`, or `//`)